# SQLite on sortable ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm trying to implement a sortable listView based on [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/australian-technology/adding-sqlite-to-a-sortable-listview/) tutorial. My database has these columns:

- ID
- NAME
- GROUP
- ORDER

When I insert new data on the database, I set NAME and GROUP columns, the ID is autogenerated. At first I don't introduce nothing in the ORDER column because I will need to modify this value later and a first time isn't relevant.

So, In a first activity I insert in the database the previously commented columns, and then I go to a listActivity where the listview with the names will be shown. I can introduce several different names and I organize them using the GROUP column. So when I want to read the database to bind the results on the listview, I do the query for a specific GROUP.

And here comes the functionality of the ORDER column, if that group already exist on the database, it will load the order and put the names in the listview in that order. But if it is a new group, the ORDER column will be empty and when sorting the items on the listview I will define the order of each item.

**My problem:**

Starting from the point that the database is empty, so no order is stablished, when I try to query a specific group, at first I was having an issue with the order column, as it was telling that the column didn't exist or something like this. But now, I get a NPE with the adapter constructor and I don't know if it has something to do with it or with the query.

This is the projection of the database columns:

```
String[] PROJECTION = {_ID, .NAME, GROUP, ORDER};
```

And here I read a specific group of the database and I bind it on the listview (and where I get NPE):

```
    String selection = GROUP + "=?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {group};
    String orden = ORDER + " ASC";
    try {
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(TravelOrderProvider.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, selection , selectionArgs , orden);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    ListAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, null, null); //NPE HERE
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    cursor.close();
```

Still have to implement the checking for if the group exists on the database or not.

LogCat added:

```
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.irvvin.carpooling/com.irvvin.carpooling.SetTravelOrderActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.findColumns(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:312)
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:66)
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at com.irvvin.carpooling.SetTravelOrderActivity.getTravelers(SetTravelOrderActivity.java:95)
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at com.irvvin.carpooling.SetTravelOrderActivity.onCreate(SetTravelOrderActivity.java:51)
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
06-10 15:52:28.473: E/AndroidRuntime(18016):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
```

Comment: @Mukesh Kumar logcat added

Comment: you are passing two NULL arguments so you get a NPE

Comment: Well, could the one who downvoted and proposed to close explain why? I think that the question is clear, is not offtopic nor a basic topic... I think there's many people here with a downvoting fever... Sorry if I'm not just as clever as most of ones here, but I'm trying to learn about this, and just downvoting without explaining how can I solve my problem is not the way to promote this great comunity. For me, this question issue is dificult to solve, that's why I have taken my time to explain it in the best way to get help to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, null, null); //NPE HERE
```

instead of `null, null` you have to pass 2 arrays:
String array with the column names and int array with the row id's (from your layout) `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

example:

```
 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, // Context.
        android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, // Specify the row template
                            // to use (here, two
                            // columns bound to the
                            // two retrieved cursor
                            // rows).
        mCursor, // Pass in the cursor to bind to.
        // Array of cursor columns to bind to.
        new String[] { ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME },
        // Parallel array of which template objects to bind to those
        // columns.
        new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });
```

Source: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#cursor

Comment: Thanks a lot, databases is still a field where I need to learn a lot